# busyindicator for angular2 kendo ui grid before data is loaded through http

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using angular2 kendo ui grid and binding data to the grid by http call

before http call returns the data i need to show busy indicator without showing grid header till data is assigned.How to achive this

Thanks,
Raghu s

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this by declaring the following within the HTML template.

Add a new div above the grid with a conditional loading text for when the grid is loading:

```
<div *ngIf="loading == true" class="loader">Loading..</div>
```

Add a div wrapper around the grid for when the loading in completed:

```
<div *ngIf="loading == false">
  <kendo-grid [data]="view1">
  <kendo-grid>
</div>
```

In `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent{
    private loading: boolean = true;

constructor(private http: Http      
    ) {
        http.get('/api/Data')
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => {

                this.loading = false;
                this.view1 = result;
                this.loadProducts();
            },
                 err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how one would do this if I use .map instead of .subscribe ? I use a behavioral subject to get the grid data and it runs asyc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of following elements adding conditionally -

```
<span class="k-icon k-i-loading"></span>
<span class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="font-size: 64px;"></span>
<span class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="color: limegreen;"></span>
```

As I did

```
<div *ngIf="!this.gridData">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="font-size: 64px;"></span>
</div>
```

As mentioned here http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/icons/#toc-flipping

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.1.0, the Kendo UI Grid for Angular features a built-in loading indicator functionality.

See the [sample documentation here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations).

The basic premise is to set the [`[loading]` property of the `kendo-grid`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-loading):

```html
<kendo-grid 
  [loading]="yourService.loading"
  ...
>
<!-- Grid column configuration -->
</kendo-grid>
```

And then in your service class set a boolean loading variable to true or false depending on the status of your queries to your remote data sources:

```js
export abstract class NorthwindService extends BehaviorSubject<GridDataResult> {
    public loading: boolean;

    private BASE_URL = 'https://odatasampleservices.azurewebsites.net/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        protected tableName: string
    ) {
        super(null);
    }

    public query(state: any): void {
        this.fetch(this.tableName, state)
            .subscribe(x => super.next(x));
    }

    protected fetch(tableName: string, state: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
        const queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}&$count=true`;
        this.loading = true;

        return this.http
            .get(`${this.BASE_URL}${tableName}?${queryStr}`)
            .pipe(
                map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
                    data: response['value'],
                    total: parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
                })),
                tap(() => this.loading = false)
            );
    }
}
```