# How can I add loading indicator or a "spinner" to a kendo angular 2 grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using kendo angular 2 grid. I would like to add a loading indicator while the the call to a web service is made. It doesn't seem that kendo grid api supports  this. How should I approach this?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893940/busyindicator-for-angular2-kendo-ui-grid-before-data-is-loaded-through-http/40035912#40035912

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that an operation is ongoing, you can just use the **[loading]** input parameter. Its default value is false, so set it to **true** to display the spinner.

If you want to apply a custom loading indicator, just use 
`<div *ngIf="loading" class="k-i-loading"></div>` and set **loading** accordingly (true when you make the request for data and false after you get the response from the web service).

From Kendo UI for Angular Documentation:

[Built-in loading indicator](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations)

[Implement a Loading Indicator Manually](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/how-to/implement-loading-indicator-manually/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use kendo-ui's `no records` template to build a custom message

Comment: In the Angular version of Kendo UI, that only works for a list view component. They don't offer a no records template option for the grid yet. I have recently created a feature request for this.

Comment: It's been over 2 years since I last looked at kendo, but it looks like the following does what I originally mentioned 4 years ago: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/NoRecordsTemplateDirective/